# PyQt5 use of QDeadlineTimer

Tags: pyqt5

Can anyone clarify why the following code is not behaving as expected.
All of the calls to `remainingTime()` are returning 0 and `hasExpired()` is returning True.
I would have expected first `remainingTime()` to have returned something close to 1000ms and the second `remainingTime()` to have returned around 500ms

```
deadline = QDeadlineTimer(1000)
print(f"deadline.remainingTime(): {deadline.remainingTime()}")
print(f"has expired: {deadline.hasExpired()}")
sleep(0.5)
print(f"deadline.remainingTime(): {deadline.remainingTime()}")
```

This code is being called from a PyQt5 button press so is operating in the main thread, not good practice, however I'm just trying to learn how to use QDeadlineTimer.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the constructor that only happens in PyQt5, not in PyQt6 nor PySide2. As a workaround, you could use [`setRemainingTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdeadlinetimer.html#setRemainingTime) right after creating it.

Comment: Many thanks for that, I'm now getting the expected values back within a millisecond.

Comment: You're welcome. I've written a message on the PyQt mailing list, I'll eventually add an answer with the above suggestion and possible version for the fix.

Comment: Can you please tell me the PyQt (not Qt!) version you're using? `from PyQt5.QtCore import *; print(PYQT_VERSION_STR)`

Comment: The version I'm using is 5.15.9

Comment: Thanks. The PyQt maintainer has [fixed the issue](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2023-May/045289.html). The next official release (probably, `PyQt-5.15.10`) will work properly, in the meantime you should consider the workaround of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in the QDeadlineTimer constructor that only happens in PyQt5 (at least until 5.15.9<sup>[1]</sup>).
It seems to work fine in PySide2 and even PyQt6 (probably due to the more strict enum system it introduced).

Using an integer as argument will result in calling the [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdeadlinetimer.html#QDeadlineTimer) that accepts a `Qt.TimerType` as argument:

```py
>>> timeout = 10
>>> QDeadlineTimer(timeout).timerType() == timeout
True
```

The problem might be in the sip file, as it seems that trying to use the explicit signature (`int, type=Qt.TimerType`) is not accepted, even if `help(QDeadlineTimer)` lists it:

```py
>>> help(QDeadlineTimer)
...
 | QDeadlineTimer(int, type: Qt.TimerType = Qt.CoarseTimer)
```

Still, trying to use the full signature, will raise an exception:

```py
>>> QDeadlineTimer(2000, type=Qt.CoarseTimer)
...
TypeError: 'type' is an unknown keyword argument
```

The simple solution is to explicitly set the remaining time:

```py
>>> deadline = QDeadlineTimer()
>>> deadline.setRemainingTime(1000)
```

### Temporary fix

<sup>***WARNING***: Please consider that the following "hack" should not be done lightly, as complex object structures (as foreign language bindings often are) may rely on rigid and delicate mechanisms that could be *fatally* broken. The fact that it works doesn't mean that it's completely safe to do it. If we're writing code for a software that requires absolute reliability, we should just do what explained above (or eventually use a basic subclass), unless we **really** know what we're doing and what that code does.</sup>

As a temporary workaround, we could create a monkey patch for the `__init__`, until we know that the bug has been fixed in PyQt5 (see below).

The trick is to create a function that virtually overrides the `__init__` of the class and checks if the first given argument **actually is** an integer.

```py
def deadlineTimerInitFix(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) and type(args[0]) is int:
        remaining, *args = args
        timerType = kwargs.pop('type', None) # fix the "type" argument issue
    else:
        remaining = 0
        timerType = None

    QDeadlineTimer.__origInit__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    if remaining > 0:
        self.setRemainingTime(remaining)
    if timerType is not None:
        self.setTimerType(timerType)

QDeadlineTimer.__origInit__ = QDeadlineTimer.__init__
QDeadlineTimer.__init__ = deadlineTimerInitFix
```

Which will result in the expected behavior:

```py
>>> t = QDeadlineTimer(1000); t.remainingTime()
1000
```

Note that the type checking is done with `if type() is`, not `isinstance()`. In PyQt5 (as in PySide2 and, in ["forgiveness mode"](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html#forgiveness-mode-and-type-hints) in PySide6 too) normal integers can be used for enums and `isinstance(SomeQtEnumOrFlag, int)` will always be true.

For instance, `setTimerType(0)` would be accepted as equivalent to `setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)`.
And if we used `isinstance(args[0], int)`, it would use that first argument as remaining time even if using a valid `Qt.TimerType` enum or flag.

This means that, with the fix above, in the case we wanted to create an arbitrary QDeadlineTimer that just specifies the timer type in the constructor, we **must** use the [`Qt.TimerType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TimerType-enum) enum.

```py
# correct:
>>> t = QDeadlineTimer(Qt.VeryCoarseTimer)
>>> t.timerType() == Qt.VeryCoarseTimer
True

>>> t.timerType()
2


# not valid, as the value would be used for the duration:
>>> t = QDeadlineTimer(2)
>>> t.timerType() == Qt.VeryCoarseTimer
False

>>> t.timerType()
1   # as in Qt.CoarseTimer, the default type
```

Be aware that the above ***MUST*** only be done *once* (otherwise we'll get recursion), possibly as soon as the first PyQt import is done in the whole application.

### Patch only when necessary

Since we may need to use QDeadlineTimer in more than one script, and (hopefully) the bug may be fixed in the future, we should add some checks to avoid unnecessary calls.

I normally create a separate file that does this sort of patches (in order to be sure that they will be applied only when necessary).

The following assumes that the bug has been fixed since PyQt 5.15.10 (remember that only *major* and *minor* version numbers of PyQt and Qt match: the build/revision number never does).

This the content of a possible `qtcompatfixes.py` file:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore

if (
    not hasattr(QtCore.QDeadlineTimer, '__origInit__')
    and QtCore.PYQT_VERSION >> 8 & 255 < 15 # PyQt older than 5.15
    or QtCore.PYQT_VERSION & 255 < 10       # 5.15.* but older than 5.15.10
):
    def deadlineTimerInitFix(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    QtCore.QDeadlineTimer.__origInit__ = QtCore.QDeadlineTimer.__init__
    QtCore.QDeadlineTimer.__init__ = deadlineTimerInitFix
```

Then, for any script that requires a QDeadlineTimer constructor with the remaining time:

```py
from PyQt5 import whatever # or any PyQt5 related import statement
import qtcompatfixes

...
```

<sup>[1] According to [this update from the PyQt maintainer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2023-May/045289.html), the issue has been fixed on the latest snapshot; if you're using local builds (or you're using a system that relies on latest official builds), just upgrade it; otherwise, if you're using PIP, wait for the next official release. In any case, the fix above should work properly and be consistent with new updates.</sup>